# Slow WIFI network connection on Lubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, download-speed

I just installed Lubuntu 17.10 as my main OS, in the past I used Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04.
The only problem is that my wireless connection is very slow, it take ages to load a webpage/youtube video and my dowloand speed is 20-30 KB/s on windows is was near 600-700 KB/s.
Here are my laptop specifications:

```
emanuel-presario-cq57-notebook-pc
    description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smp vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 3549MiB
     *-cpu
          product: AMD E-450 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 1237MHz
          capacity: 1650MHz
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni monitor ssse3 cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch ibs skinit wdt hw_pstate vmmcall arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save pausefilter cpufreq
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 14h Processor Root Complex
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          configuration: latency=32
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Wrestler [Radeon HD 6320]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
             resources: irq:29 memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:f0400000-f043ffff memory:c0000-dffff
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 11
             bus info: pci@0000:00:11.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=64
             resources: irq:19 ioport:4118(size=8) ioport:4124(size=4) ioport:4110(size=8) ioport:4120(size=4) ioport:4100(size=16) memory:f0449000-f04493ff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 12
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=32
             resources: irq:18 memory:f0448000-f0448fff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 12.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=32
             resources: irq:17 memory:f0447000-f04470ff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: SBx00 SMBus Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 42
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             configuration: driver=piix4_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 40
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:16 memory:f0440000-f0443fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 14.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
             version: 40
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 14.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.4
             version: 40
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 14.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.5
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=32
             resources: irq:18 memory:f0446000-f0446fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 15
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:24 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:f0300000-f03fffff ioport:f0000000(size=1048576)
           *-generic
                description: Unassigned class
                product: RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=rtsx_pci latency=0
                resources: irq:27 memory:f0300000-f0300fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 15.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:25 ioport:2000(size=4096) ioport:f0100000(size=1048576)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
                logical name: eno1
                version: 05
                serial: 00:9c:02:89:72:a2
                size: 10Mbit/s
                capacity: 100Mbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                resources: irq:28 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0104000-f0104fff memory:f0100000-f0103fff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3)
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 15.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.3
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:26 memory:f0200000-f02fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Broadcom Limited
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
                logical name: wlp7s0b1
                version: 01
                serial: c0:18:85:30:b5:d6
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=4.13.0-21-generic firmware=610.812 ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:23 memory:f0200000-f0203fff
        *-usb:3
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=32
             resources: irq:18 memory:f0445000-f0445fff
        *-usb:4
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 16.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=32
             resources: irq:17 memory:f0444000-f04440ff
     *-pci:1
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 12h/14h Processor Function 0
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 101
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
          version: 43
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:2
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 12h/14h Processor Function 1
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 102
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:3
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 12h/14h Processor Function 2
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 103
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 12h/14h Processor Function 3
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=k10temp
          resources: irq:0
     *-pci:5
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 12h/14h Processor Function 4
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 105
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.4
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:6
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 12h/14h Processor Function 6
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 106
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.5
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:7
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 12h/14h Processor Function 5
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 107
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.6
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:8
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 12h/14h Processor Function 7
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 108
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.7
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-scsi
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVDRAM GT50N
             vendor: hp
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: MP00
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

And here are some informations about network cards:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 05
       serial: 00:9c:02:89:72:a2
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:28 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0104000-f0104fff memory:f0100000-f0103fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlp7s0b1
       version: 01
       serial: c0:18:85:30:b5:d6
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=4.13.0-21-generic firmware=610.812 ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:23 memory:f0200000-f0203fff
```